# Set multiple routes on same function in Controller of CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

I have a situation where I have to get multiple parameters and these parameters are dynamic also by means user can enter 2 ,3 ,4 any number of parameters. I know if I have a static count of parameters then I can use (:any) in routes.

```
$route['function_name/(:any)/(:any)'] = 'Controller/function_name/$1/$2';
```

but this scenario is different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$route['function_name/(.+)'] = 'Controller/function_name/$1';
```

With this you can pass multiple params within single route.